# QueryTable.Refresh causes incomplete OLE action; how to complete?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to auotmate this report and have written VBA to perform various tasks, then I call each of them sequentially in a "RunAll" sub. I have data from an Access query to a tab in my workbook for a pivot table.

I've discovered that when I run this:

```
Sub QueryTableRefresh()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("data").Activate
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```

it creates an incompelte OLE action with Access, which causes a Read Only instance of Access to open when I run the below ("TableRefresh" is a function with delete and append queries):

```
Public Sub RefreshAccessTables()

    Dim acApp As Object
    Dim db As Object
    Set acApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("P:\Reports\Daily Origination Volume\Daily Origination Volume.accdb")
    Set db = acApp
    acApp.Run "TableRefresh"
    acApp.Quit
    Set acApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

The read only instance prevents the writing actions of the delete and append queries. This is not the sequence in which these two run within my RunAll, but the workflow would require that the RunAll would be run again if any updates are made, which then causes the conflict.

I've run the Access function from Excel multiple times back to back and have no problems, until I run the querytable refresh. Refreshall causes the same problem.

How do I update only my query table in Excel, without leaving this OLE action incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem may be alleviated by choosing another method to import the data, that being MS Query. Rather than choosing the "From Access" option for importing data, choose "From Other Sources" then "From Microsoft Query."

After using this import method, I refreshed it multiple times back to back. Immediately following the refreshing, I was able to open the source database in read/write mode.